# "Show applications" shows previous version of software

Tags: gnome, gui, gnome-shell, android-studio, pycharm

I got an update in PyCharm. Clicking on the update button redirected me to the website where I downloaded the updated version. The new version needed no installation and can be directly used from an `.sh` file. But my "Show applications" still showed the previous version of PyCharm.

Is there any way I can point to newer version of PyCharm so to access it through "Show applications"? The same problem can also be found in other software like Android Studio.

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 GNOME.

Comment: First you'll have to locate where the desktop launcher (*.desktop file) for the application is placed. Possible directories are `/usr/share/applications`, `/usr/local/share/applications/`, `~/.local/share/applications`. See if you can find `pycharm.desktop` or something similar in those directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install **Main Menu** (aka `alacarte`) application either from *Ubuntu Software* or by running

```
sudo apt install alacarte
```

Then follow the steps below.

1. Launch *Main Menu* from *Show Applications* and look for Pycharm. You'll probably find it under the **Programming** category.
2. Once found, right click on it and select *Properties*. A dialogue box should pop up.
3. Enter the `/path/to/the/.sh` (full path like like `/home/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop/...` etc.) in the *Command* box and click on *OK*.

Logout and login again. Now you should be able launch the new version from *Show Applications*.